# How to make a program write all this information in text file

Tags: python

```
import random
from random import randint
val1 = 0
val2 = 0

while val1 != 6 or val2 != 6:
    val1 = randint(1, 6)
    val2 = randint(1, 6)
    print(val1,val2)
```

I have this code what makes random numbers till 6,6
and i what to program write this random numbers to txt file

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You might want to continue reading the tutorial: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) builtin in write (`w`) mode:

```
import random
from random import randint
val1 = 0
val2 = 0

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    while val1 != 6 or val2 != 6:
        val1 = randint(1, 6)
        val2 = randint(1, 6)
        f.write(f'{val1} {val2}\n')
```